# How to automatic return value of "PI" from function without assign in operation part of function body

Tags: function, pascal

My code is under , i will be gratefull for any suggestion

```
(* //const
//pi=3.1415926;
//uses
//mathh.inc; *)
var
r,pole_kola,obwod_kola: real;

function Pi: valreal;
begin
 Pi:=3.1415926;
end;

procedure dane();
begin
  read(r);
end;

procedure obliczenia();
begin
  pole_kola:= {pi}Pi*r*r;
  obwod_kola:= 2*{pi}Pi*r;
end;

procedure wyniki();
begin
  writeln('pole koła: ',pole_kola:4:8);
  writeln('obwód koła: ',obwod_kola:4:8);
end;

begin
  writeln('podaj promien r: ');
  dane();
  obliczenia();
  wyniki();
end.
```

How i can use function Pi :
https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/pi.html

to return automatic value of "PI" from function without assign in operation part of function body if i try modify function get back

```
Function result does not seem to be set
```

```
function Pi() :valreal;

begin

end;

begin
    WriteLn('pi = ', Pi():1:20);
end.
```

```
Compiling main.pas
main.pas(1,10) Warning: Function result does not seem to be set
Linking a.out
8 lines compiled, 0.1 sec
1 warning(s) issued
pi = 0.00000000000000000000
```

in program

```
 ./main
podaj promien r: 
6
pole koła: 0.00000000
obwód koła: 0.00000000

```

Comment: You don't need to define the function `Pi` yourself. It's builtin in pascal. But if you define a function named `Pi` yourself it has to return a value ...

Answer (score -2):

In the task, I wanted to automatically use a ready value for PI (3.14…) without using my function. My function didn’t returned a value because I didn’t assigned one. Like we see here:

```
function Pi() :valreal;

begin
             //here is nothing but must be returned a value
end;

begin
    WriteLn('pi = ', Pi():1:20);
end.
```

Going by @derpirscher’s comment, the function written by hand always needs to return something. So I commented part of my syntax, and used the built-in function named PI. (Pascal includes that function.)

```
(* function pi: valreal; // If I define my own function, it must return a value
begin
 pi:=3.1415926; // So in the body of the function, we must assign value
end; *)
```

We see that here

```
procedure obliczenia();
begin
  pole_kola:= {pi}Pi*r*r; // using build in function 
  obwod_kola:= 2*{pi}Pi*r; // as above
end;
```

If we need to use the value of PI in our task/homework, we can use predefinied built-in functions because it is easier; it is good practice to use less syntax in our code.

Must remember: If we define a function i.e., named Pi ourselves, it has to return a value.

Under the comment, the entire syntax of my code with corrections:

```
var
r,pole_kola,obwod_kola: real;

(* function pi: valreal; // If I define my own function, it must return a value
begin
 pi:=3.1415926; // So in the body of the function, we must assign value
end; *)

procedure dane();
begin
  read(r);
end;

procedure obliczenia();
begin
  pole_kola:= {pi}Pi*r*r; // using build in function 
  obwod_kola:= 2*{pi}Pi*r; // as above
end;

procedure wyniki();
begin
  writeln('pole koła: ',pole_kola:4:8);
  writeln('obwód koła: ',obwod_kola:4:8);
end;

begin
  writeln('podaj promien r: ');
  dane();
  obliczenia();
  wyniki();
end.
```